# I had an error when I passing a string argument to a function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm sorry. I don't know how to describe this problem carefully.so I hope put my code first.

```
var test = 'less';
function test_I(tite) {
    console.log(tite);
}
var repeat = "test_I('"+test+"')";
setTimeout(repeat,10);
```

The code is right, but when I change:
`var repeat = "test_I(' "+test+" ')";`
to:
`var repeat = "test_I("+test+")";`,

I get this error in Chrom's console. Why do I need a `' '` When I pass a
String parameter? The error is below.

[image: error]

Comment: Please don't pass strings to `setTimeout`. Pass a function and arguments, instead: `setTimeout(function, timeout, arg1, arg2, ....)`

Comment: Look for the 2nd answer in the dupe target.

Answer (score 0):

> Why I need a ' ' When I pass a String parameter

To ensure that `less` is passed as a **`String` instead of a variable**.

If you don't use `''`, this code `var repeat = "test_I("+test+")";` becomes

```
var repeat = "test_I(less)";
```

and when `setTimeout` executes the same it will look for variable `less`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, yes ... interesting fun.  If you break down your string to what the JavaScript engine will see, it becomes:

```
test_I(less)
```

and less doesn't exist.

if you added "`var less='less'`" at the beginning of your code, it would then work.